# setting classpath in manifest.mf

Tags: eclipse, manifest

Hi I have an eclipse application which has MANIFEST.MF in which I am trying to set classpath like

```
Class-Path:
 ./lib/*
```

where . is current directory and lib is the location where I have all my jars kept that are needed by the application.
But it doesn't pick the jars.

But if I specify ./lib/library1.jar, it does pick the library1.jar 
I also tried `.lib/library1.jar;./lib/library2.jar;` etc. It doesn't work this way too.

How do I specify multiple jars in a classpath in MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer , the MANIFEST.MF is very picky in white spaces and lines
The entry should be like this -( may be useful for someone ):

Class-Path: ./lib/library1.jar ./lib/library2.jar

no extra lines, only white spaces in between

Comment: Actually tried Class-Path: ./lib/*. It won't work! I think building a jar from MANIFEST.MF doesn't support wildcards...is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

In jar manifest files, you don't use ';' to specify multiple files, you simply use whitespace. *In addition* you also don't want to use . to specify the current directory. The file paths should be specified to run from the current directory by not using any non-whitespace syntax at the start of the path.

Try modifying your Class-path entry to be

```
Class-Path: lib/library1.jar lib/library2.jar
```